# Programmatically force spotlight to index metadata for specific invisible file types

Tags: cocoa, spotlight

Is there a way to accomplish this?

The reason for this is I am trying to force spotlight to receive automatic updates when invisible files and folders are added/removed. This behavior I believe is a side effect of not indexing the meta-data (but I could be wrong). I came to this conclusion from this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487641/spotlight-nsmetadataquery-with-invisible-items-do-not-auto-update).

Is the solution writing a mdimporter? Will it even work for invisible file types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, it seems there is no way to force indexing of invisible folders.

I am instead searching all folders and getting updates for all folders. (Still very fast if you are wondering)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Spotlight expert, but I'll take a stab anyway.

My understanding is that Spotlight will only index files of types that it knows about. If the files that you want to have indexed are of a custom type, then you will need to write a mdimporter.

I don't know if Spotlight will index invisible files.

To force spotlight to rerun, check out the `mdimport` command.

Comment: “I don't know if Spotlight will index invisible files.” As I mentioned in my answer to his other question, it will not.